# Asymmetric serialization/deserialization using Symfony Serilizer

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, deserialization

I'm using Symfony 5.4 and its Symfony/Serializer component.

I receive a JSON payload like the following one:

```
{
  "name": "Truck",
  "age": 23
}
```

I wish I could deserialize it to the following model, where the `name` JSON field would be mapped onto the `lastname` User class attribute:

```
class User {
  protected lastname;
  protected age;
}
```

My issue here is that the deserialization fails since there is no `name` field in my model.

Sure I could add a `name` field to my User model, and write its getter/setters as follow and use Serializer's group not to serialize the `name` field :

```
public function getName(): string
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

public function setName(string $name): User
{
    $this->lastname = $name;

    return $this;
}
```

But this looks hackish. Anyway, on top of the aforementioned, I need any `User` entity to be serialized to :

```
{
  "lastname": "Truck",
  "age": 23
}
```

As a consequence, I can not use `@SerializedName('name')` here.

What would be the cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an `AdvancedNameConverterInterface`.

A very simple, naive implementation:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\AdvancedNameConverterInterface;

class UserNameConverter implements AdvancedNameConverterInterface
{

    public function denormalize(string $propertyName, string $class = null, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if ($class === User::class && $propertyName === 'lastname') {
            return 'name';
        }

        return $propertyName;
    }

    public function normalize(string $propertyName, string $class = null, string $format = null, array $context = []): string
    {
        return $propertyName;
    }
}
```

Check for the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing).

To [enable it in the configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#enabling-a-name-converter), you should be able to do:

```yaml
framework:
    # ...
    serializer:
        name_converter: 'App\YourNamespace\UserNameConverter'
```

Comment: thank your for your response. Unfortunately I already have a MetadataAwareNameConverter set on my ObjectNormalizer, so I'm unsure how to benefit from annotations and UserNameConverter. Is it possible ?